# Git remote branch not showing, so I cannot merge

Tags: git, github, branch

I tried to merge with a remote branch and I am having problems.

My git remote network looks like this:

https://github.com/liuduan/CAT-APP-PROJECT/network

```
>> git branch -r
SS-Master/master
origin/Department_Head
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/HEAD_2
origin/President
origin/master
```

It did not show the branch for **"master/ashimaSharma"**. How do I have git to show the **"master/ashimaSharma"** branch?

Then I tried:

```
>>git fetch –-all
Fetching origin
Fetching SS-Master

>>Fetching HEAD_2
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/liuduan/CAT-APP-PROJECT/commit/d54b6f1db7ff624970105fdfe5c0a1aa60a9d7b2/' not found
error: Could not fetch HEAD_2
```

Actually I do not really care about HEAD_2 branch, but I need to show the branch **"master/ashimaSharma"**, so I can merge.

I got a suggestion from max630 to remove HEAD_2, and I removed it successfully.

I did **”get fetch –-all”**, and **”get remote -v”**,

```
git remote -v
SS-Master       https://github.com/sumit0704/CAT-APP-PROJECT/ (fetch)
SS-Master       https://github.com/sumit0704/CAT-APP-PROJECT/ (push)
origin  https://github.com/liuduan/CAT-APP-PROJECT (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/liuduan/CAT-APP-PROJECT (push)
```

But the **“master/ashimaSharma”** is still not showing up.

Comment: what does `git remote -v` print?

Comment: Edit it into the question

Answer (score 0):

You have remote named "HEAD_2", pointing to some nonexistent URL. You should remove it.

```
git for-each-ref 'refs/remotes/HEAD_2/' # ***verify that it's empty, so that you don't delete anything important***
git remote remove HEAD_2
```

PS: Then  you should add the ashima1491's fork as another remote:

```
git remote add ashima1491 https://github.com/ashima1491/CAT-APP-PROJECT
```

Comment: Yes. I have successfully removed HEAD_2.

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182516/a-git-remote-branch-is-not-showing-so-i-cannot-merge-2/)

> Remote branch won't show any work done in the forked repositories. In your case the remote branches are Department_Head, HEAD_2, President and master. If you really want to merge "ashima1491"'s changes, ask him to send you a pull request.
>
> Alternatively -
> You can also add another "remote" (the other github repository) by using
> `git remote add origin1 https://github.com/ashima1491/CAT-APP-PROJECT.git`
> This will add another remote named "origin1" which points to ashima1491's github repository. Next you can pull her code to your repository using -
> `git pull origin1 master`
> given you are currently at your master branch this will "pull" her master branch to your master. You can then add, commit and push.