# A git remote branch is not showing, so I cannot merge. (2)

Tags: git, merge

A git remote branch is not showing, so I cannot merge. (2)
The link for the previous question is here, but you do not need to read the previous question in order to understand this question.
[Git remote branch not showing, so I cannot merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014716/git-remote-branch-not-showing-so-i-cannot-merge/46179408#46179408)

I hope to merge with “master/ashimaSharma” and having problem.
The network graph looks like this, please see the 2017-Aug and -Sept part:
https://github.com/liuduan/CAT-APP-PROJECT/network
I hope to merge with **“master/ashimaSharma”** but I cannot see the branch.
I did **”get fetch –-all”**, and **”get remote -v”**,

```
>> git remote -v
SS-Master       https://github.com/sumit0704/CAT-APP-PROJECT/ (fetch)
SS-Master       https://github.com/sumit0704/CAT-APP-PROJECT/ (push)
origin  https://github.com/liuduan/CAT-APP-PROJECT (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/liuduan/CAT-APP-PROJECT (push)
```

What should I do to see and merge with **“master/ashimaSharma”**?

Comment: @markroxor What is a **“pull request”**, and how can she send?
Will I be able to merge he code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git remote branch not showing, so I cannot merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014716/git-remote-branch-not-showing-so-i-cannot-merge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote branch won't show any work done in the forked repositories. In your case the remote branches are `Department_Head`, `HEAD_2`, `President` and `master`. If you really want to merge "ashima1491"'s changes, ask him to send you a pull request.

Alternatively -
You can also add another "remote" (the other github repository) by using
`git remote add origin1 https://github.com/ashima1491/CAT-APP-PROJECT.git`
This will add another remote named "origin1" which points to ashima1491's 
 github repository. Next you can pull her code to your repository using -
`git pull origin1 master`
given you are currently at your `master` branch this will "pull" her `master` branch to your `master`. You can then add, commit and push.

Comment: How can she send a “pull request”? Will I be able to merge he code? I need to merge her code with "President".

Comment: Both the repos have totally different commit histories, unfortunately sending a pull request is not possible. BTW you can send it via - [this link](https://github.com/ashima1491/CAT-APP-PROJECT/compare/master...liuduan:master). I think you should manually copy the files. Though this is a very crude solution. You could wait for other answers. Regards.

Comment: I can see **"Singh/master"**. The **"ashimaSharma/master"** is derived from **"Singh/master"**. Why is it "entirely different commit histories."?

Comment: I think one of you deleted the commits manually or forced the commits. This is evident from [her commit history](https://github.com/ashima1491/CAT-APP-PROJECT/commits/master) and [yours](https://github.com/liuduan/CAT-APP-PROJECT/commits/master). They don't seem to have a common commit to start with. One of you messed with git.

Comment: FYI you can easily send a PR from [mayukh698's repo to yours](https://github.com/mayukh698/CAT-APP-PROJECT/compare/master...liuduan:master).

Comment: Hi, markroxor, Yes. It works. I did **"git remote add origin1 https://....."**, and **"git pull origin1 master"**. It works. Thank you very much.